# How to get each Item Value from Recyclerview and Store it in Local Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

1.I am having recyclerview like e-cart/food ordering items in which I am adding quantity of the each item with (+) and (-) buttons, then how can i get the value of each item with item name, item rate and quantity.

2.How can i store the obtained values from recycler view in local database.

//This is my adapter class

```
package com.myapplication.chaiwalacustomer.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.myapplication.chaiwalacustomer.R;
import com.myapplication.chaiwalacustomer.model.TeaListPOJO;
import com.myapplication.chaiwalacustomer.utils.AppConstants;
import com.myapplication.chaiwalacustomer.utils.Base64;

import java.util.List;


public class TeaListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeaListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        //private int num=0;
        private List<TeaListPOJO> teaItemList;
        private Context mContext;
        private Cursor cursor;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView tvitemName, tvitemRate,number;
            public ImageView ivItemImg;
            public Button btnIncrease,btnDecrease;
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                tvitemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
                tvitemRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_price);
                ivItemImg= (ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.iv_item);
                number=(TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.integer_number);
                btnIncrease =view.findViewById(R.id.btn_increase);
                btnDecrease = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_decrease);

            }
        }


        public TeaListAdapter(List<TeaListPOJO> teaItemList) {
            this.mContext=mContext;
            this.cursor=cursor;
            this.teaItemList = teaItemList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.rv_placeorder_items, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder (itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            TeaListPOJO tealist = teaItemList.get(position);
            holder.tvitemName.setText(tealist.getItemName ());
            holder.tvitemRate.setText(AppConstants.INDIAN_RUPEE_SIGN.concat (tealist.getItemRate ()));
           // holder.number.setText (tealist.getQty ());
            //num=Integer.parseInt (tealist.getQty ());

            //String title = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();

            holder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int num=0;
                    try{

                        num = Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString());
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    num++;
                    holder.number.setText ((num+""));

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            holder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int num=0;
                    try{

                        num = Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString());
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    if(num>0)
                        num--;
                    holder.number.setText ((num+""));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            byte[] decodedString = new byte[0];
            try {

                decodedString = Base64.decode(tealist.getImageStr(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                // tenantModelPOJO.setLogo(decodedString);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                holder.ivItemImg.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 50, 50,false));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }




        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return teaItemList.size();
        }
    }
```

//This is my activity

```
public class PlaceOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppConstants, View.OnClickListener, WLAPIcalls.OnAPICallCompleteListener {

    private List<TeaListPOJO> teaList = new ArrayList<> ();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TeaListAdapter mAdapter;
    private View view;

    int count=0;


    private Context mContext = PlaceOrderActivity.this;
    private int itemCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_place_order);

        setRecyclerView (view);
        getallTeaItems();
        // prepareMovieData();
    }



    List<TeaListPOJO> getTeaItemList(String str) {
        Gson gson = new Gson ();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TeaListPOJO>> () {
        }.getType ();
        List<TeaListPOJO> myModelList = gson.fromJson (str, listType);
        return myModelList;
    }

    private List<TeaListPOJO> getallTeaItems() {
        if (new AppCommonMethods (mContext).isNetworkAvailable ()) {
            WLAPIcalls mAPIcall = new WLAPIcalls (mContext, getString (R.string.getTeaItem), this);
            mAPIcall.GetTeaItemList ();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText (mContext, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
        }
        return null;
    }

    void setRecyclerView(View view){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new TeaListAdapter (teaList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getApplicationContext ());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator ());
        recyclerView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++)
        {
            view=recyclerView.getChildAt(i); // This will give you entire row(child) from RecyclerView
            if(view!=null)
            {
                EditText editText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_time);
                String text=editText.getText().toString();
                if (text.equals(i)){
                    // Do your stuff, after comparison
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAPICallCompleteListner(Object item, String flag, String result) throws JSONException {
        if (getString (R.string.getTeaItem).equals (flag)) {
            Log.e ("Result", result);
            teaList = getTeaItemList (result);
            setRecyclerView (view);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the best practice would be to use onclick listeners on your plus and minus button and use your pojo class to SET the updated item details. Anyways try to avoid tightly coupled code.

Comment: Which local database are you using? And do as @PembaTamang suggested

Comment: Would recommend going through [link](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/ee5a525f-0ba3-4d25-ba29-1fa1d6c567b8/concepts/771f758c-d57d-481d-82ba-e78df608a753) . And for database I recomend using Room since it can save you a lot of time and there are some really good tutorials (one is in link above).

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable such as selectedMap of `HashMap<Object,Integer>` type. Once you increase the count then use the condition

```
HashMap<Object,Integer> selectedMap = new HashMap();

        //In increase count onClick
        if(selectedMap.containsKey(teaList)) {
            int prevCount = selectedMap.get(teaList);
            selectedMap.put(teaList, prevCount++);
        } else {
            selectedMap.put(teaList, 1);
        }

        //In decrease count onClick
        if(selectedMap.containsKey(teaList)) {
            int prevCount = selectedMap.get(teaList);
            if(prevCount == 1)
                selectedMap.remove(teaList);
            else
                selectedMap.put(teaList, prevCount--);
        }
```

Now this map has all the selected items. When you want to store the item in DB then simply iterate this HashMap and the value of each item will give you the item count.

Regarding storing the data into the database, first decide the type of database you are going to use and then look for the help how the data will be inserted and fetched as per your requirement.

Comment: where should i use this in my adapter or in activity class